# phpmailer secure approach by placing credentials out of the web root in INI file

Tags: php, phpmailer

first of all thank you for your time and helping me on this.
I have a simple contact form and i'm using phpmailer.

I want to store credentials in an INI file out of webroot and then include it in my mail.php file which is the mail sending script.

How to write the INI content and how to call them on mail.php file?

This is my HTML file which is contact us form:

```
<h3><font style="line-height:170%" size="4"> <a id="contactus">Contact us form</a>  </font></h3>
            <form method="post" action="email.php" accept-charset="UTF-8">          
            <p>         
            <label>your name</label>
            <input name="dname" type="text" size="30" />
            <label>your email</label>
            <input name="demail" type="text" size="30" />


            <label>your domain name</label>
            <input name="ddomain" type="text" size="30" />


            <label>Message</label>
            <textarea name="dmessage" id="dmessage" rows="5" cols="5"></textarea>
            <br />  
            <input class="button" type="submit" value="submit"/>        
            </p>        
            </form>             
            <br />
```

and this is the  email.php file:

```
   <?php
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
$email = $_REQUEST['demail'] ;
$message = $_REQUEST['dmessage'] ;
$ddomain = $_REQUEST['ddomain'] ;
require("PHPMailer_v5.1/class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->IsSMTP();


$mail->Host = "localhost";

$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 

$mail->Username = "info@example.com"; // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "this is the password"; // SMTP password


$mail->From = $email;

$mail->AddAddress("info@example.com");

$mail->WordWrap = 50;

$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = $ddomain;

$mail->Body    = $message;
$mail->AltBody = $ddomain;

if(!$mail->Send())
{
   echo "Error <p>";
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo "we have received your email";
?>
```

I want to store credentials in  a safe place.

Another problem is that whenever someone open email.php file in browser ( example.com/email.php) an empty email will be sent to me, how to prevent it?
I want the email.php file to be executed only a result of a customer's contact via filling the form and not by directly opening the email.php file

Thank you all

Comment: You don't need an .ini. it can be a plain php file: `<?php $username='foo'; $password='bar';`. As long as it's outside of your webroot, it's unreachable unless someone gains shell access to your server.

Comment: To protect from empty emails just check for $_POST being non empty at the starting of the script. If it is empty (if customer is sending a POST request) then just exit from the script.

Comment: even inside if php is working, noting will be shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

if (empty($_REQUEST['demail']) || empty($_REQUEST['dmessage'])) {
    die();
}

$constants = parse_ini_file("/outside/web/sample.ini");

header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
$email = $_REQUEST['demail'] ;
$message = $_REQUEST['dmessage'] ;
$ddomain = $_REQUEST['ddomain'] ;
require("PHPMailer_v5.1/class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->IsSMTP();


$mail->Host = "localhost";

$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 

$mail->Username = $constants['username']; // SMTP username
$mail->Password = $constants['password']; // SMTP password


$mail->From = $email;

$mail->AddAddress("info@example.com");

$mail->WordWrap = 50;

$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = $ddomain;

$mail->Body    = $message;
$mail->AltBody = $ddomain;

if(!$mail->Send())
{
echo "Error <p>";
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
exit;
}

echo "we have received your email";
?>
```

INI file (sample.ini) looks like:

```
username = "info@example.com"
password = "PASSW0RD"
```

Comment: ahh ok. had not run the code but was pretty sure it would work :)

Comment: wouldn't personally use parse ini when you could just make it a php file, but that's me.

Comment: yeah, overhead of parsing it in each request

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your helps.
I did some change on your code and it is excatly what is want.
instead of saying:

```
if (empty($_REQUEST['demail']) || empty($_REQUEST['dmessage'])) {
    die();
}
```

i used this one:

```
    if (empty($_REQUEST['demail']) || empty($_REQUEST['dmessage'])) {
   echo "Please fill-in Email and Message sections completely!";
   exit;
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: yeah that is one way of alerting. I thought it was more of an internal file and you did not want people to know that what all parameters are mandatory for it to work :)

Comment: Thank you neo for your care